# Death of King Solomon

Tags: king-solomon

In my King James Bible, I Kings 11:40 "...Solomon therefore sought to kill Jeroboam: but he arose, and fled into Egypt to Sesac the king of Egypt, and was in Egypt till the death of Solomon..."

My questions: What happened in Egypt with Sesac the king of Egypt? What was the relationship between Solomon and Sesac? How long was Jeroboam in Egypt? How did King Solomon Die?

Thank you for helping me with this.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya. You may want to split these up into several different questions, as otherwise it might get closed as Too Broad.

Comment: To VTCers: How is this comparative religion?

Answer (score 3):

King Solomon was crowned at the age of 12 and reigned for 40 years. He died of natural causes at the age of 52.

Rashi states that he married the daughter of Pharaoh in the fourth year of his reign.
[I Melachim 11:39](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15895#v=39&showrashi=true)

> **but not for all times.:** For in the days of the Messiah the kingdom
>   will be restored to him. In Seder Olam (ch. 15) I found: “I shall
>   afflict David’s descendants because of this. Corresponding to the
>   thirty-six years that Solomon was married to Pharaoh’s daughter, for
>   he married her during the fourth year of his reign.

The [Jewish Virtual Library](https://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/jeroboam) states

> Details of Jeroboam's rebellion are not reported in the Books of
>   Kings, but it appears that it took place in the second half of
>   Solomon's reign.